# Infinite orthonormal sequence in V whose span is dense in V

Tags: vector-spaces

Here is a part of a proof that I am trying to understand.

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional inner product space, and let $\{v_{1}, v_{2},\dotsc\}$ be an orthonormal sequence such that span$\{v_{1}, v_{2},\dotsc\}$ is dense in $V$. Let $x \in V$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By the density of span$\{v_{1}, v_{2},\dotsc\}$ in V, there is some $y\in $span$\{v_{1}, v_{2},\dotsc\}$ such that $\|y-x\|<\varepsilon$. Then $y=\Sigma^{N}_{j=1}\alpha_{j}v_{j}$ for some $\{\alpha_{1}, \dotsc, \alpha_{N}\}$.

What I don't understand is how we know that $y$ is a linear combination of finitely many vectors in the sequence, and doesn't the density mean that we would have $\|y-x\|=0?$

Comment: That's the definition of $\operatorname{span}$, finite linear combinations of the elements. The density alone cannot give you distance $0$. If the distance is zero then $x=y$, but this implies that $x$ is in the dense set. A dense set doesn't have to be the entire space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, re-stating the definitions may help you a lot.

> If $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}⊆V$, where $V$ is an arbitrary vector space, then $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}$ is defined as:
>   $$\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}=\left\{\sum_{k=1}^nλ_k,v_{i_k}:n\in\mathbb{N},λ_k\in\mathbb{C},i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$

That is, *by definition*, the linear span of some vectors is the set of all *finite* linear combinations of them!

> A subset $D\subseteq X$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be dense in $X$ if for every $x∈X$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $a∈D$, such that $d(a,x)<\varepsilon$.

So, a dense subset is "arbitrarily close" to any point of $X$, but not exactly on overy point of $X$ - note that $\lVert y-x\rVert=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$, so what you write in your question is evidently wrong.

Reconsider the statement using these two definitions now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I totally forgot that the span is only finite linear combinations!

Comment: You're wellcome!